# How do I add an echo inside a query?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, posts

I'm trying to show posts from a certain category on a page like his:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=category1'); ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

This works. However, I'd like 'category1' to be taken from a custom field of the page. Something like this (incorrect code incoming):

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_cat_name', TRUE); ?>'); ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

How could I make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it in this way:

```
$custom_cat_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_cat_name', TRUE);
query_posts('category_name=' . $custom_cat_name);
```

Hope this helps!